# How to properly send JSON metadata value to Woocommerce API

Tags: c#, json, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

My c# application creates products using the Woocommerce.NET NuGet package.

I'm sending metadata with the `key`: `woodmart_variation_gallery_data` and `value`: `{"5543":"5519"}`

But the plugin that uses this metadata can't use the value, **however**, when checking the metadata in the database, it's exactly the same as I sent it.

But WordPress should serialize it unless I'm sending the JSON the wrong way.

For example, I need to send this JSON to Woocommerce:

```
{"5543":"5519"}
```

Here's how I would to this using code:

```
Product product = new Product();
//add some stuff like price

product.meta_data = new List<ProductMeta>()
{
    new ProductMeta()
    {
        key = "woodmart_variation_gallery_data",
        value = "{\"5543\":\"5519\"}"
    }
}
await wcObject.Products.Add(product);
```

When this run, what I'm expecting to see in the database postmeta is serialized code:

```
a:1:{i:5543;s:4:"5519";}
```

But what I see is `{"5543":"5519"}` It's supposed to be serialized by wordpress/woocommerce, but it's not?

Comment: @dbc I added some code, and the result I'm expecting and what I got.

Comment: Should I serialize the JSON myself before sending it to the API? @dbc

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure.  At this point your question looks fine, I just don't know the answer.

Comment: @dbc Thanks for at least trying, sorry for the huge delay in response though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sharp Serialization Library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/csphpserial/)